# Install Android app on device through wifi - no usb or emulator

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, usb, wifi

Just as it says in the title.

It seems my smartphone data connectors are broken, and the emulators run far too slow on my computer (surprisingly because it is i7).

So, is there any way I can use an alternative to usb debugging through WIFI instead of usb?

Comment: You can have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cyanogenmod, developer options provides a way to operate adb over network.

1) Enable 'ADB over network' in Developer option of Android Settings

2) When you enable 'ADB over network' and if you are connected to internet, you will find your wlan device ip address below the given text. Lets say it is a.b.c.d:5555

3) Run 'adb connect a.b.c.d:5555'

4) Now you are good to use adb to install apps or for debugging purposes

Other devices require root access to operate adb over wifi. Given below link describes the process for same:

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)